# Jquery UI Slider with ajax, php and maybe mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an Slide like this:

```
$(function () {

    /*--------------------------------------------------
    Plugin: Slider
    --------------------------------------------------*/

    /* Increment Slider */
    $( "#incrementSlider" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value:1993,
        min: 1914,
        max: 2013,
        step: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#incrementAmount" ).text ("Birthday: " +  ui.value);

        }
    });

    $( "#incrementAmount" ).text ( "Birthday: " + $( "#incrementSlider" ).slider( "value" ));


});
```

If the user now select over the slider the birthday I want to show some Infos.

For example the User takes 1980:

```
Infotext 1 belong to 1980,
Infotext 2 belong to 1980,
Birthday   belong to 1980,
Infotext 3 belong to 1980,
Infotext 4 belong to 1980
```

I need it so, that I can use it free in a text, but of course it must change automatically if the user change the birthday in the slider.

It don't must be and I don't prefer a solution with mysql if there is any other way.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me; can you edit the question and give more specific about what you are trying todo? What does *"I can use it free in a text"* mean?

Comment: Yes of course. I have an php document with an text it this text i want to insert the infotexts on different positions. So I think I must use php variables. It is the self php document the slider runs.

Comment: How much text are talking about?

Comment: For the Infotexts only some words.

For Example 1980 - Infotext 1 = cold.

Full text example: The weather on {Birthyear} was very {Infotext1 = cold}.

I hope you know what I mean :-)

Comment: Hi @TrivoXx I'd like to get your thoughts on the answer I provided...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so a solutions without MySQL; assuming

- we're talking about a limited set of values like hot and cold (rather than long paragraphs of text)
- the data is static and never changes

**Including all the data when the screen loads**

You could just include the data in a javascript file eg create and link to a file called **sliderdata.js**. Inside the file create a hash table of the data (aka a javascript associative array)

```
var dataForInfoText = {
    "1980": "cold",
    "1985": "hot",
    "1990": "cold",
};
```

then inside you're slide event handler add the following js

```
infoText1.text(dataForInfoText[ui.value]);
```

> Note: Associative arrays allow you to access the values in 2 ways either `dataForInfoText.propertyName1` or `dataForInfoText['propertyName1']`

and heres a fiddle to show this working http://jsfiddle.net/sDBTy/ although in the example I've included the data directly in the example (not a separate file, which you could also do)...

**Variation - Loading data for the year as required**

First we need a helper method which allows us to dynamically load script files as required:

```
function loadModule(name, callback) {
    $.ajax({type: "POST"
        , url: name
        , dataType: "script"
        , success: callback
    });     
}
```

Create a script file for each year which contains all the info-text that you need. The contents of the 1980.js could look something like this

```
var infotextdata = {
    "text1" : "cold",
    "text2" : "its 1980"
};
```

and *1981.js*

```
var infotextdata = {
    "text1" : "hot",
    "text2" : "this one was born 1981"
};
```

**Note: this time I've included 2 properties per object text1 and text2, but this could be any number depending on the info-text you need to show**

Finally amend the slide event handler to look like this

```js
// declare sliderTimeout outside of the handler
clearTimeout(sliderTimeout);

sliderTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
    loadModule(selectedValue + ".js", function () {
        infoText1.text(infotextdata.text1);
        infoText2.text(infotextdata.text2);
    }), 2000);
```

Where `selectedValue + ".js"` would result in a url eg *1980.js*; so basically we have a *.js* for each year and we set the info-text by first loading the js file for that year and setting the text first 1 and 2 as required.

The `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout`, add a delay so that the data file is only loaded when the user pauses on a year for 2 seconds, obviously you can change the delay as required, or remove it completely...

Personally I think this 2nd method is the closest you're going to get to ajax without a database (assuming the data is static). You're bypassing php, so its more efficient; directly asking your web server for the data and gives the flexibility of not getting data for all years unnecessarily...

Comment: @TrivoXx Thanks for accepting but I'm interesting to know what you did in the end?